# Testing the value of a field against a list of strings

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes

I want to test the value of a field against a list of possible strings for inclusion (value contains none of these strings) or exclusion (value contains at least one of the strings).
The difficulty is: the possible string(s) can be part of the fields value.

Example:

Strings: '>50% green', '10-50% red', 'tree', 'apple'

Value: '>50% green | 10-50% tree | '

Which syntax would find the '>50% green' in this value?

I have tried values and arrays, e.g. array_contains, where the array is the list of strings and the value is the current value of the field - which only finds the cases, where the value is an exact match of the string, but not those, where the string is part of the value.

I'm new to this - and out of ideas after 3 hours of digging into the manual.

Comment: I guess you're working with QGIS? If so, please add the corresponding tag, thank you.

Comment: @Erik: yes, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `array_intersect` once you convert `value` to an array of strings.

From the help panel of the expression editor:

> **function array_intersect**
> Returns TRUE if at least one element of array1 exists in array2.
>
> ***syntax***
> array_intersect(array1,array2)

```sql
array_intersect(
    array('>50% green', '10-50% red', 'tree', 'apple'),
    -- `trim()` is used to remove leading and trailing whitespace after string_to_array is used. 
    -- The delimiter could also be ' | ', but this way handles cases where there is no space either before or after the | character.
    array_foreach(string_to_array(value, '|'), trim(@element))
)
```

###### Result using *Select by expression* tool

[image]

##### Alternative with no `string_to_array`

This expression will return `true` if any of the strings are found in `value`.

The result of `array_foreach` is an an array of `0` and `1` depending whether the string is found in `value`. Using `array_contains(array, 1)` returns true if there is at least one match.

The `%` symbols concatenated on the beginning and end of each element in the strings array are wildcards, they represent 0 or more of any character, which allows for partial matches.

```sql
array_contains(
    array_foreach(
        array('>50% green', '10-50% red', 'tree', 'apple'), 
        value like '%' || @element || '%'
    ),
    1    
)
```

Comment: Thank you, Matt.

Comment: Looking forward to trying that...